# Creating a File from byte array

Tags: java, file-io, arrays

So - I've got a third party library that needs a `File` as input.  I've got a `byte array`.

I don't want to write the bytes to disk .. I'd like to keep this in memory.  Any idea on how I can create a `File` from the provided `byte array` (without writing to disk)?

Comment: If you have the source code to the third party library, you could modify it. Just make sure you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sorry, not possible. A File is inherently an on-disk entity, unless you have a RAM disk - but that's not something you can create in Java.

That's exactly the reason why APIs should not be based on File objects (or be overloaded to accept an InputStream).

Comment: What about using RandomAccessFile?

Comment: This doesn't extend File or so. Live with it (and blame those 3rd party API authors for such a flawed API, best what you can try is posting a bug report at their issuetracker).

Comment: Correct, and the java.io.File object is merely an abstract representation of the path.  I have decompiled and updated third party libraries for less, but you should be able to get away with writing a file with a GUID name to a tmp directory and then passing that path on.

Comment: Not quite... it also has some useful functionality to return a URL or URI which could be leveraged... See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

There's one possibility, but it's a real long-shot.

If the API uses `new FileReader(file)` or `new FileInputStream(file)` then you're hosed, but...

If it converts the file to a URL or URI (using `toURL()` or `toURI()`) then, since `File` is not final, you can pass in a subclass of `File` in which you control the construction of the URL/URI and, more importantly, the handler.

But the chances are VERY slim!

Answer (score 0):

So I see there is an accepted answer (and this is old), but I found a way to do this. I was using the IDOL On Demand API and needed to convert a `byte array` to a `File`.

Here is an example of taking a `byte array` of an image and turning into a `File`:

```
//imageByte is the byte array that is already defined
BufferedImage image = null;
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte);
image = ImageIO.read(bis);
bis.close();

// write the image to a file
File outputfile = new File("image.png");
ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputfile);
```

And so `outputfile` is a `File` that can be used later in your program.