# How do I create a java.io.File from a byte []

Tags: java, file, byte

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating a File from byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704554/creating-a-file-from-byte-array)

Hello everyone I have a problem
I have an array of bytes loaded with a file .doc inside
I need to convert this byte array to a java.io.File
who can post a piece of Java code that performs the request from me?
thanks to all

Comment: *"who can post a piece of Java code that performs the request from me?"*  SO is not a code factory.

Answer (score 0):

Use file output stream:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("filename");
fos.write(byteArray);
fos.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a ByteOutputStream with your binary representation, and then:

```
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream ("c:\\a.doc"); 
byteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(outputStream);
byteArrayOutputStream.close();
```

I think it will be enough

Hope this helps

Comment: This is one step too many... [`outputStream.write(byteArray);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write(byte[])).

Comment: @Adam, your edit is invalid. closing the `byteArrayOutputStream` achieves nothing.