# from byte [] a FileInputStream, File or POIFSFileSystem

Tags: java, byte, fileinputstream

using a utility method of alfresco can find a. doc file and put it into a byte array
my goal and to succeed through this byte array to generate one of these:

```
java.io.File;
java.io.FileInputStream;
org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem
```

then read and edit it through this class org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument

please help me thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a java.io.File from a byte \[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343234/how-do-i-create-a-java-io-file-from-a-byte)

Comment: Not convinced that's a duplicate. I think OP has already created byte[] from File and needs help with the next step.

Answer (score 1):

A [HWPFDocument](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/HWPFDocument.html) accepts an `InputStream`, so the answer is simply to construct it with a `ByteArrayInputStream`:

```
byte[] buf = ... // loaded by Alfresco
HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(new ByteArrayInputStream(buf));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you mean putting the .doc file into byte array, then try this....

```
File fKey = new File("d:/MyKey.doc");
FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(fKey);
byte[] decode =  new byte[(int)fKey.length()];
fi.read(decode);
```